# Is there a way to invoke a method with a MethodCall[] as a parameter?

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I need to invoke a method : myMethod(double ... tab)
But I get the elements of this array by other MethodCall.
For now what I do :

```java
    MethodCall anotherMethod(MethodCall[] t){
        MethodCall form = MethodCall.invoke(myMethod);
        for (int i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
            form = form.withMethodCall(t[i]);
        }
    }
```

But with that, myMethod is declared like this :

```java
double myMethod(double t1, double t2, double t3, ..., double t10){...}
```

I would like to know how to do with bytebuddy to use instead :

```java
double myMethod(double ... tab){...}
```

or

```java
double myMethod(double[] tab){...}
```

Moreover the attribute "form" is a dynamic retrieved method, so the number of loops performed in "for" is never the same. So sometimes I can invoke a form method like this : `method1(double val){...}` or `method2(double val1, double val2){...}` or `method3(double ... tab){...}`

Answer (score 0):

Varargs do not really exist in byte code, only in Java code. You have to assign each parameter (which can be a `MethodCall`) where the single values need to be a `MethodCall` and the array another one. Creating arrays from `MethodCall`s is unfortunately not supported.